# É possível implementar o método onLongClickListener no marker no mapa?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação que trabalha sobre o Google Maps API v2.

Já defini o método `onClickListener()` para abrir uma `WindowManager` de modo a exibir o nome do ponto de interesse e o endereço desse local.

Agora eu quero que, ao clicar continuamente num `Marker`, exiba uma `WindowManager` diferente para o utilizador puder guardar esse local como favorito numa tabela `SQLite`.

Desde já agradeço toda a ajuda...

Answer (score 0):

Eu aconselho seguir este caminho para poder trabalhar em cima das possibilidades:

**1 -**  Ao criar um marcador**(addMarker)**, já salve imediatamente no banco as informações de latitude e longitude.

**2 -** Agora abaixo serão situações na qual será necessário um update naquele especifico ponto que você registrou no banco e de acordo com cada evento você realiza as atualizações:

```
mapa.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
            // Primeiro contato

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
            // Fim contato

        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            // Contato contínuo

        }
    });
```

> Agora você deve está se perguntando porque **não** buscar uma possibiludade para **onLongClickListener** em um **marker**? Bem... Você não precisa esperar que o seu cliente der um segundo clique em cima do marcador para poder salvar uma informação no banco, uma vez que sua aplicação tem o objetivo de salavr localizações e também ele irá preferir movimentar um marcador pelo mapa, do que ficar clicando em cada ponto do mapa após erra um posicionamento ou querer atualizar aquela determinada posição.

[Fonte](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener)

Comment: Eu percebi a ideia. Mas é que eu não estou a adicionar os marcadores manualmente. Estou a chamá-los através de um ArrayAdapter<String> para exibir os tipos de locais num spinner e mostrar somente o tipo de lugar que o utilizador selecionou, utilizando a API do GooglePlaces. Tendo em conta isto como faço para guardar a latitude e a longitude no SQLite?

Comment: Muito simples...Já já atualizo.